# Set table width by using a class name or/and role name

Tags: angularjs, css, css-tables

[image]

How can I set the table width to `style="width:1201px"` by using a class name and a role name.
I have tried by giving the css as :

```
.activitySequenceTable table[role=treegrid] {
    width: 1201px;
}
```

But its not affecting.

Comment: can you add some html as well ?

Comment: Please refer the image @GokulShinde

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, add your real code instead. Also, please be sure you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try like `.activitySequenceTable .k-grid-content table {width:1201px}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to ensure not to be overridden.

```
.activitySequenceTable table[role=treegrid] {
    width: 1201px !important;
}
```

Comment: @forgottofly Yes, `!important` almost always works and still it is almost never the solution. Instead of using `!important` I'd suggest finding out where that inline style is coming from, why it is `0px` and how you can change that.